# How can make json output

Tags: json, perl

I want make json output using below code.

But I can't make json output

below is my code but not work

===================================================================

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "{\n";
print "\t\"data\":[\n\n";

for (`cat usable | awk 'NF>0 && NR>8 && NR < 15'`)
{
($poolname, $devconfig, $unablegbs, $freegbs, $usedgbs, $full, $comp) = m/ (\S+)/;

print "\t,\n" if not $first;
$first = 0;

print "\t{\n";
print "\t\t\"{#POOLSNAME}\":\"$poolname\",\n";
print "\t\t\"{#DEVCOFIG}\":\"$devconfig\",\n";
print "\t\t\"{#UNABLEGBS}\":\"$unablegbs\",\n";
print "\t\t\"{#FREEGBS}\":\"$freegbs\",\n";
print "\t\t\"{#USEDGBS}\":\"$usedgbs\",\n";
print "\t\t\"{#FULL}\":\"$full\",\n";
print "\t\t\"{#COMP}\":\"$comp\",\n";
print "\t}\n";
}
print "\n\t]\n";
print "}\n";
```

===================================================================

input file is below

```
Symmetrix ID: 000000000000

                   S Y M M E T R I X   P O O L S
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pool         Flags  Dev              Usable       Free       Used Full Comp
Name         PTECSL Config              GBs        GBs        GBs  (%)  (%)
------------ ------ ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ----
SAS600_R1    TFFDEI RAID-5(3+1)     78725.1    160.3    64.8   94    0
SAS600_R2    TFFDEI RAID-4(3+1)     725.1    120.3    666.8   83    0
SAS600_R3    TFFDEI RAID-3(3+1)     7825.1    1260.3    6564.8   34    0
SAS600_R4    TFFDEI RAID-2(3+1)     7875.1    160.3    664.8   4    0
SAS600_R5    TFFDEI RAID-1(3+1)     872.1    1210.3    6564.8  1     0

  Total                            ---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ---    -
  GBs                                 78725.1    12160.3    66564.8   84    0

Legend:
  (P)ool Type:
    S = Snap,  R = Rdfa DSE  T = Thin
  (T)echnology:
    S = SATA, F = Fibre Channel, E = Enterprise Flash Drive, M = Mixed, - =     N/A
  Dev (E)mulation:
    F = FBA, A = AS400, 8 = CKD3380, 9 = CKD3390, - = N/A
  (C)ompression:
    E = Enabled, D = Disabled, N = Enabling, S = Disabling, - = N/A
  (S)tate:
    E = Enabled, D = Disabled, B = Balancing
  Disk (L)ocation:
    I = Internal, X = External, M = Mixed, - = N/A`
```

===================================================================

OUTPUT want look like below

```
{
"{#POOLINDEX1}":"SAS600_R5","{#RAIDVALUE1}":"RAID-5(3+1)","   {#USABLEVALUE1}":"725.1","{#FREEVALUE1}":"160.3","{#USEDVALUE1}":"564.8"},"   {#FULLVALUE1}":"84%","{#COMPVALUE1}":"0"},
"{#POOLINDEX2}":"SAS600_R3","{#RAIDVALUE2}":"RAID-3(3+1)",{#USABLEVALUE2}":"78725.1","{#FREEVALUE2}":"1160.3","{#USEDVALUE2}":"6564.8"},"    {#FULLVALUE2}":"54%","{#COMPVALUE2}":"0"},
"{#POOLINDEX3}":"SAS600_R2","{#RAIDVALUE3}":"RAID-1(3+1)","    {#USABLEVALUE3}":"7725.1","{#FREEVALUE3}":"12160.3","{#USEDVALUE3}":"66564.8"},"        {#FULLVALUE3}":"8%","{#COMPVALUE3}":"0"}
}
```

Comment: Use the JSON module: https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON

Comment: Get that Python out of your Perl.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't edit the existing one with a new revision. (Especially not to one that contains code that's simply never going to work, because you can't mix perl and python in the same script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two answers to this question:

- use the [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm) module to assemble JSON. It's less painful.
- this looks like the Symmetrix CLI output. Set [`-output XML`](https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-6812) and you'll get machine readable output. `XML` not `JSON`, but it's actually easier to convert from one to the other than hand parse anyway.

To answer your question as asked though:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON; 

my @header = qw ( name flags raid usable_gb free_gb used_gb full_perc comp_perc ); 

my $stuff;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my %this_row; 
    if ( m/RAID/ ) {
        my @fields = split; 
        @this_row{@header} = @fields; 
        push ( @$stuff, \%this_row ); 
    }
}

print to_json ( $stuff, { pretty => 1 } );

__DATA__    
Symmetrix ID: 000000000000

                   S Y M M E T R I X   P O O L S
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pool         Flags  Dev              Usable       Free       Used Full Comp
Name         PTECSL Config              GBs        GBs        GBs  (%)  (%)
------------ ------ ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ----
SAS600_R1    TFFDEI RAID-5(3+1)     78725.1    160.3    64.8   94    0
SAS600_R2    TFFDEI RAID-4(3+1)     725.1    120.3    666.8   83    0
SAS600_R3    TFFDEI RAID-3(3+1)     7825.1    1260.3    6564.8   34    0
SAS600_R4    TFFDEI RAID-2(3+1)     7875.1    160.3    664.8   4    0
SAS600_R5    TFFDEI RAID-1(3+1)     872.1    1210.3    6564.8  1     0

  Total                            ---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ---    -
  GBs                                 78725.1    12160.3    66564.8   84    0

Legend:
  (P)ool Type:
    S = Snap,  R = Rdfa DSE  T = Thin
  (T)echnology:
    S = SATA, F = Fibre Channel, E = Enterprise Flash Drive, M = Mixed, - =     N/A
  Dev (E)mulation:
    F = FBA, A = AS400, 8 = CKD3380, 9 = CKD3390, - = N/A
  (C)ompression:
    E = Enabled, D = Disabled, N = Enabling, S = Disabling, - = N/A
  (S)tate:
    E = Enabled, D = Disabled, B = Balancing
  Disk (L)ocation:
    I = Internal, X = External, M = Mixed, - = N/A`
```

### Output:

```
[
   {
      "full_perc" : "94",
      "flags" : "TFFDEI",
      "comp_perc" : "0",
      "name" : "SAS600_R1",
      "used_gb" : "64.8",
      "free_gb" : "160.3",
      "usable_gb" : "78725.1",
      "raid" : "RAID-5(3+1)"
   },
   {
      "flags" : "TFFDEI",
      "comp_perc" : "0",
      "name" : "SAS600_R2",
      "full_perc" : "83",
      "usable_gb" : "725.1",
      "raid" : "RAID-4(3+1)",
      "used_gb" : "666.8",
      "free_gb" : "120.3"
   },
   {
      "usable_gb" : "7825.1",
      "raid" : "RAID-3(3+1)",
      "free_gb" : "1260.3",
      "used_gb" : "6564.8",
      "name" : "SAS600_R3",
      "flags" : "TFFDEI",
      "comp_perc" : "0",
      "full_perc" : "34"
   },
   {
      "free_gb" : "160.3",
      "used_gb" : "664.8",
      "raid" : "RAID-2(3+1)",
      "usable_gb" : "7875.1",
      "full_perc" : "4",
      "name" : "SAS600_R4",
      "comp_perc" : "0",
      "flags" : "TFFDEI"
   },
   {
      "usable_gb" : "872.1",
      "raid" : "RAID-1(3+1)",
      "used_gb" : "6564.8",
      "free_gb" : "1210.3",
      "flags" : "TFFDEI",
      "comp_perc" : "0",
      "name" : "SAS600_R5",
      "full_perc" : "1"
   }
]
```

Comment: thank your answer. I have some question. 
I want change below

before
`cat usable | awk 'NF>0 && NR>8 && NR < 15'`

after
`cat $1 | awk 'NF>0 && NR>8 && NR < 15'`

Comment: Then take a look at `<>` - if you replace `<DATA>` in the above with `<>` it will read from either `STDIN` or file as named on command line. (`myscript.pl usable`). But seriously - export to `XML` is the easiest answer.

Comment: hello. thank you very much.
first I want make SYMMATRIX storage monitoring shell for zabbix.
are you have SYMMATRIX monitoring shell? or do you know zabbix?

and I really want execute in command line like "script.pl 0000". 0000 is sid

script include below symcli command.
/opt/emc/SYMCLI/bin/symcfg -sid 0000 list -pool -gb

Comment: please check my question

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question.  Don't amend the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all. Your program almost works. You just need a g modifier on your regular expression:

```
($poolname, $devconfig, $unablegbs, $freegbs, $usedgbs, $full, $comp) = m/ (\S+)/g;
```

And remove the `,` after `$comp` to be valid JSON.

Your program could do with a couple of improvements. I would suggest

1. Using [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) package to create JSON.
2. Using perl inline syntax, instead of calling `cat` and `awk`. Perl has support for everything that you can do with awk. If you continue to use an external call then stop with [cat abuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: thank your answer. I have some question.
 I want change below
before 
`cat usable | awk 'NF>0 && NR>8 && NR < 15'`
 after 
`cat $1 | awk 'NF>0 && NR>8 && NR < 15'`

Comment: `$filename = 'usable';` and `cat $filename` will do that, but I still believe you should use @Sobrique's answer where you don't execute another program, when it's really easy to do it inline in perl.